# Convert &#8211; into &ndash; PHP

Tags: php, string, html-entities

I have a string.

For example -> `"Pirate Code &#8211; PVP Battles at Sea  Trailer"`

and I wanna **str_replace** it with `"Pirate Code &ndash; PVP Battles at Sea Trailer"`
but its failing.

In actual both of `&#8211;` and `&ndash;` represent "–". I want to convert `&#8211;` into `&ndash;`

So I can perform the function.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: i tried htmlentities($str); but it does not converts them

Comment: Either [`get_html_translation_table()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php) your way out of it, or just use `html_entity_decode()` I guess? https://3v4l.org/TeKVi

Answer (score 1):

you can use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for that

```
str_replace("&#8211;", "&ndash;", "Pirate Code &#8211; PVP Battles at Sea  Trailer");
```